# How to Download and view profile picture in ionic 3 with sharepoint?

Tags: android, angular, sharepoint, ionic3, office365api

Iam new in ionic with sharepoint
I have developed a Mobile app using ionic3 with sharepoint.
Now i have to get user profile picture in my app.

I have tried these are the way can't achieve here is my tried code.

First way tried like this

Passing Url:-

```
"https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/QA/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname=admin@abc.onmicrosoft.com"
```

Second way tried like this

Passing Url:-
These url iam geting using people picker result. PictureURL property

```
"https://abc.sharepoint.com/User Photos/Profile Pictures/admin_abc_onmicrosoft_com_MThumb.jpg"
```

These Second method always return 
401 UNAUTHORIZED

Above url using to call this method.

```
public downloadFile(url: string, fileName: string) {

   let options = this._apiHeaderForImageURL();
   this._http.get(url, options)
      .subscribe((data) => {      
         //here converting a blob to base 64 For internal view purpose in image src
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsDataURL(data.blob());
         reader.onloadend = function () {
         console.log("Base64", reader.result);
      }


      //Here Writing a blob file to storage 
      this.file.writeFile(this.file.externalRootDirectory, fileName, data.blob(), {       replace: true })
         .then((success) => {
            console.log("File Writed Successfully", success);
         }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error While Wrinting File", err);
         });
      });
 }


public _apiHeaderForImageURL() {
   let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' });
   headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token"));
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, responseType: 3 });                                  
   return options;
}
```

The first api call worked fine result also sucess but image not displayed properly. Thats the problem iam facing.

The result comes an default image like this only.

[image]

pls help me to achieve this. Any help warmly accepted.
Iam doning long time stuff to achieve this still i cant achieve pls give some idea.
Is any other way is available to get user picture in ionic 3 using sharepoint?

Comment: Normally URL parameters aren't enclosed by `""` instead, they are encoded. Try the first url but instead of the way you're currently sending: 

`let url = "abc.sharepoint.com/sites/qa/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=s&accountname=" + encodeURIComponent("abc@sharepoint.com")`

Comment: tried still same default image will return. any other idea. thanks man.